# HTML table overflow - how to stretch other content on the page to match the table width

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a one large table and a footer. The table doesn't fit horizontally, so there is a scroll bar (which is fine), but the problem is that the footer that is below the table does not stretch to match the table width. See the following CodePen that illustrates the problem:

https://codepen.io/pglazkov/pen/XWEPjvo

[image]

How to make the div containing the table (red box) and the footer (green box) match the table width?

Here is the code from the above example:

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 800px;
}

.table-container {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company2</th>
        <th>Contact2</th>
        <th>Country2</th>
        <th>Company3</th>
        <th>Contact3</th>
        <th>Country3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <footer>This is footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the parent element (`.table-container` and in example `<section>`) of the `<table>` around the `<table>` and the `<footer>`. The key ruleset is:

```css
/* In example, it is <section> */
.table-container {
  width: max-content; /* Set width to the width of it's content */
}
```

All block-level elements like `<div>` and `<footer>` are `width: 100%` by default so adding it isn't normally needed.

By setting the parent to the width of it's content at it's fullest extent, the `<table>` will expand to meet the widths of all of it's `<th>` and `<td>` without breaking the text into new lines. Now because the `<footer>` is naturally `width: 100%`, it will conform to the parent element's width which in turn is dictated by the width of the `<table>` via `width: max-content` of the parent element.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

main {
  margin: 10px auto;
}

section {
  background-color: red;
  width: max-content;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Company2</th>
          <th>Contact2</th>
          <th>Country2</th>
          <th>Company3</th>
          <th>Contact3</th>
          <th>Country3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <footer>This is footer</footer>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Good tip about `width: max-content;` - it seems to be a step in the right direction, however it doesn't solve the whole problem because setting it on the `.container` div makes it match the table width while I need it to stay the 100% of the viewport width and have a horizontal scroll (`overflow: auto; `). See this updated example: https://codepen.io/pglazkov/pen/zYWmyKz.

Comment: ok, the problem can be solved by adding another div around `.table-container` and `footer` and setting `width: max-content;` on that one. Please update your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: IC, ok updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using overflow:auto in the main container, you can use it in "table-container" class.

```
.table-container {
  background-color: red; 
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Then the scroll bar will be at the bottom of the table, not the page, which is not desirable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the desired changes just replace this

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%; // require changes
}

.table-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%; //require chanes
  overflow-x: auto; // require chnages
}
```

Explain: Let the **.container** and **.table-container** expand until where table width goes then **overflow-x: auto;** for **.table-container**, it will make scroll only to table but footer will have only width of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped table-container around footer as well and added width fit content to it.

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 800px;
}

.table-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: fit-content;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company2</th>
        <th>Contact2</th>
        <th>Country2</th>
        <th>Company3</th>
        <th>Contact3</th>
        <th>Country3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>This is footer</footer>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to be written in `.container` that the `width` should be in `auto`. By this, you can add more colors and the bgcolor of the table will be increased automatically.

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.table-container {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company2</th>
        <th>Contact2</th>
        <th>Country2</th>
        <th>Company3</th>
        <th>Contact3</th>
        <th>Country3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <footer>This is footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: still issue is there